# Timer in Foxpro (how to pause and control the time)

Tags: timer, foxpro, visual-foxpro

I run this code:

```
1.THIS.ENABLED = .F.     && suspend timer
2.
3.lnTotFiles = ADIR(laFiles, "*.ERA")
4.FOR lnCntFiles = 1 TO lnTotFiles
5.     DO myprocess WITH laFiles[lnCntFiles,1]
6.     IF THISFORM.cmdPause.CLICK()
7.          MESSAGEBOX("Click OK to resume processing")
8.     ENDIF
9.NEXT lnCntFiles
10.
11.THIS.ENABLED = .T.   && reactivate timer
```

The problem is, THISFORM.cmdPause.CLICK() in the Timer event always returns .T. whether or not I click on the Pause command button.

cmdPause.CLICK() containes this:

```
1.IF THISFORM.cmdPause.CAPTION = "Pause"
2. THISFORM.cmdPause.CAPTION = "Resume"
3. THISFORM.tmrChkDir.ENABLED = .F. 
4.ELSE 5. THISFORM.cmdPause.CAPTION = "Pause" 
6. THISFORM.tmrChkDir.ENABLED = .T. 
7.ENDIF
```

So how should I test if the Pause button was clicked within the FOR-NEXT loop in the Timer event?

Comment: this is cmdPause.CLICK() containes:

Comment: `1.IF THISFORM.cmdPause.CAPTION = "Pause"
2.    THISFORM.cmdPause.CAPTION = "Resume"
3.    THISFORM.tmrChkDir.ENABLED = .F.
4.ELSE
5.    THISFORM.cmdPause.CAPTION = "Pause"
6.    THISFORM.tmrChkDir.ENABLED = .T.
7.ENDIF
`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
THIS.ENABLED = .F.     && suspend timer
lnTotFiles = ADIR(laFiles, "*.ERA")
FOR lnCntFiles = 1 TO lnTotFiles
DO myprocess WITH laFiles[lnCntFiles,1]
DOEVENTS     
DO WHILE .T.
IF THISFORM.cmdPause.ENABLED
EXIT
ENDIF
DOEVENTS
ENDDO
NEXT lnCntFiles
THIS.ENABLED = .T.   && reactivate timer
```